# PHP Not Including Cross-Domain (Same Server) File

Tags: php, arrays, include

I have a tracking system built onto "track.com", and I want to track my other sites' performance on the same server.  This requires that I include a universal "track.com/tracking.php" on every page, so that I can grab all of the required arrays.  I will note - while the domains are on the same server, their IP addresses are different.

At first when I tried to include tracking.php, I got the "URL file-access is disabled" php error.  I loaded up my php.ini file, and while allow_url_fopen was there and set to On, allow_url_include didn't exist.  So I added it in and set it to On.

I'm not getting a file-access error anymore, but the include isn't working.  I get no errors on the page, but when I try to echo an array from tracking.php, nothing comes out.  I've tried linking to the file in these ways with the same result:

```
include('http://track.com/tracking.php');
include('/home/track/public_html/tracking.php');
include('../home/track/public_html/tracking.php');
```

I'm not really sure where to go from this point.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: While preferably I'd like a solution that let's me include this cross-domain file, I'm open to other solutions.  I want to have a singular file that I can edit that will affect activity on all of my domains.

Comment: Does the access log on the `track.com` server show that the file is being downloaded? If you `var_dump()` the array, do you see an empty array or is it undefined?

Comment: your server is parsing the output, your won't get your php sourced in. you will have to rename it to a text file and then include

Comment: You can't do it the first way but the second include should work. The only reason the second line wouldn't work would be if the path is incorrect.

Comment: Barmar - the array renders as NULL if I dump it

DevZer0 - including the txt file does indeed work, but then that .txt file is easily readable by anybody who happens to discover the URL of that file.  do you know of any way to protect against this?